# How to use a stream between a flutter app and a flask api to check for user states?

Tags: flutter, flask

I'm developing a Flutter app in which I want to query user states from the Flask REST API. For example, whether the user is verified and logged in. These states determine which screen will be loaded.
In Flutter. I want to use the StreamBuilder something like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<CurrentUser?>(
            stream: //TODO: stream method,
            builder: (content, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              if(snapshot.hasError) {
                print(snapshot.error)
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                //TODO: page router
              } else {
                return const LoginPage();
              }
            }));
```

note: The StreamBuilder should update or get a CurrentUser object via flask when the state changes.
If the state does not change, it will continue to listen. If the user is not logged in, the object will be null.
In flask I want to create a route for the stream. When a state changes, the change of the user object will be sent using this route.

```
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    ...
    return changed_user_state
```

If necessary, other methods should also be able to respond via this stream, if a state changes.

```
@app.route('/other-route')
    def change_state():
        return changed_user_state via the stream
```

My concern is very theoretical and I don't know if it can be implemented in this way. If not, I would be grateful for any better idea.  If it can be implemented in this way, I would be very grateful for a few code snippets. I don't know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any updates\answers?